# A question about differentiable manifold definition

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The following definition is taken from the book "Analysis on Manifold, Munkres, p.196"

[k-manifold definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbEre.png)

Can someone explain why is condition (2) necessary? If we have (1) and (3), can't we use the inverse function theorem to build a local $C^1$ inverse?

EDIT:
What I meant by "use the inverse function theorem" is that we use the fact that $rank(D\alpha(x)) = k$, to invert (locally) $k$ lin. ind. components of $\alpha$.

EDIT2:
Let's say that $α : U → ℝ^n$, with $U ⊆ ℝ^k$ open, is such that $α$ is $C^1$ and, for $x_0 ∈ U$, $rank(Dα(x_0)) = k$. I claim that exist:

1. An open set $U_0 ⊆ U$, with $x_0 ∈ U_0$;
2. An open set $V_0 ⊆ ℝ^n$, with $α(U_0) ⊆ V_0$;
3. And a $C^1$ function $g : V_0 → U_0$, such that $g|α(U_0) = α^{-1}$.

Proof: Because $rank(Dα(x_0)) = k$ there are $k$ lin. ind. rows in $Dα(x_0)$, let's call $π$ the projection of $ℝ^n$ onto these $k$ coordinates. The function $f = π∘α$ is $C^1$ and $det(Df(x_0)) ≠ 0$, so we can use the inverse function theorem to build a local inverse of $f$. Meaning that there is a open set $U_0 ⊆ U$ such that $f(U_0)$ is open, $x_0 ∈ U_0$ and $f_0 : x ↦ f(x) : U_0 → f(U_0)$ has a $C^1$ inverse. Let's put $V_0 = π^{-1}(f(U_0))$ and $g = f_0^{-1}∘π : V_0 → U_0$. The function $g$ is $C^1$, $x ∈ U_0 ⇒ g(α(x)) = x$, and $y ∈ α(U_0) ⊆ V_0 ⇒ α(g(y)) = y$.

Comment: The inverse function theorem only applies when the derivative in invertible. $D\alpha(x)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ so it cannot be invertible.

Comment: @Daniel Apsley $D\alpha(x)$ is from $R^k$ to $R^n$, I meant take $k$ lin. ind. components and invert it. You don't need the others.

Comment: again, it is not clear how you want to invert it. If $k<n$, then $D\alpha(x)$ is injective but not surjective, so definitely not invertible, so you can't apply the inverse function theorem. I suggest you read ahead in Munkres's text, because right after this definition he gives a bunch of examples talking about the geometric meaning of various conditions (and also shows that it is possible to satisfy two of the conditions but not the third)

Comment: @peek-a-boo I edited the post to include a bettere explanation of what I meant.